# iOS - Objective-c protocol in swift with private access

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-protocols

I have imported some objective-c code in my swift project and that contains some protocols. When I use that objective-c protocol in swift, that throws like below,

> Method 'xxxxfunc' must be declared public because it matches a
> requirement in public protocol 'xxxxDelegate'

it force me, to make it as public function, but I need it as private. How to make those functions in private access?

Comment: If the protocol is public and the type conforms to the protocol publicly, the method has to be public, because everybody who knows about the protocol knows about the method.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Obj-C - Swift interoperability. This would be the case even if the protocol itself was pure Swift.

Protocol conformance cannot be made private, because that would enable several conformances to the same protocol with different implementations. The visibility of the protocol conformance (and hence all protocol requirements) must be the same as that of the protocol.

So if you have a `public protocol`, all properties/methods required by the protocol must also be declared `public` on the conforming type. If your protocol is `internal`, then you can have the properties/methods as `internal`.

The closest you can get to your desired behaviour is declaring the protocol and the conforming type in the same file, making the protocol `private` and then you only need to mark the conforming type's properties/methods `fileprivate`.

However, you should rather rethink your architecture. Is a protocol really the best data structure to suit your needs? Do those properties/methods really need to be private on the conforming types?